# How can I solve "Cannot call method "addL" of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, methods

I was trying to make by myself a "library" for my personal project which uses local storage for nearly everything and I got this error.

The Browser I am using is Google Chrome on the last version. It says no error line on the console and the error is:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'addL' of undefined.

**JavaScript**

```
function local (title) {
    var storeTitle = title;
    this.addL = function(lString) {
        var storeText = lString;
        localStorage.setItem(storeTitle, storeText);
    };
    this.removeL = function() {
        localStorage.removeItem(storeTitle);
    };
    this.getL = function () {
        localStorage.getItem(storeTitle);
    };
};
```

I can't find the error and when I google `Cannot call method ... of undefined` it shows a lot of pages but with different content, not the one I'm looking for. I found from Google Maps API to jQuery API.

I learned this "way" from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232444/sub-object-functions-in-javascript) here StackOverflow.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Which line is erroring? Please paste the actual error message too.

Comment: The browser is Google Chrome(see the tags), it says no line and the actual message is on title. But yes, will improve the post :) @leon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `new` keyword. So try this:

```
new local("locally").addL("stored")
```

Comment: MAN! that solved the WHOLE problem. THANK.YOU.SO.MUCH! Now let me love you endlessly :)